# How to load specific storyboard depending on device in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

**This is a repost since the other one was closed.**

I have trouble with auto layout, so I would just prefer to make two storyboards, iPad and iPhone. All I want is to detect the type of device it is or the size and then display their respected storyboard. I have tried just about every solution I have found on StackOverflow and I cannot get it to work.

Currently, I detect the size of the device on the AppDelegate.m under DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions then load the storyboard and set the initialViewController. When I run the iPad simulator it runs and displays correctly, and in the console it returns the correct storyboard and view controller. However, when I run the iPhone simulator it displays the iPad storyboard but in the console, it shows that it returned the iPhone storyboard and the correct initialviewcontroller.

Also, I am new to Objective-C but getting the hang of it. Thanks, hope someone can help.
Here is my App Delegate code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *rootViewController;
    
    // detect screen height
    int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.height;
    NSLog(@"The fixed height is %i", height);
    
    // determine if this is an iPad
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        
        // it's an iPad
        if (height >= 1024) {
            
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
            
            NSLog(@"LOADING MAIN/IPAD STORYBOARD");
        }
        
    } else {
        // it's an iPhone
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
        rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"iPhoneLoginViewController"];
        
        NSLog(@"LOADING IPHONE STORYBOARD");
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Root View Controller: %@", rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"Storyboard: %@", storyboard);
    
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}
#pragma mark - UISceneSession lifecycle


- (UISceneConfiguration *)application:(UIApplication *)application configurationForConnectingSceneSession:(UISceneSession *)connectingSceneSession options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)options {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return [[UISceneConfiguration alloc] initWithName:@"Default Configuration" sessionRole:connectingSceneSession.role];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didDiscardSceneSessions:(NSSet<UISceneSession *> *)sceneSessions {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

@end
```

Here is my Info.plist:

[Info.plist Property List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV10i.png)

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
    <string>iPhone</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
```

Below are screenshots of iPad VS iPhone Results:

[iPad Simulator with its correct storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEj09.jpg)

[iPhone Simulator showing incorrect storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbPVq.jpg)

[iPhone Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTP5.png)

Comment: can you provide the source code?

Comment: I'll suggest you to use same class (h&m) for iPhone & iPad for resuability. No problem in different storyboards

Comment: You need to post your full code for SceneDelegate and AppDelegate so we can see what you're doing. As a side note - the images you've shown could easily be managed with auto-layout and a single Storyboard.

Comment: Source code of the entire project? And good point I will use the same class for both. Thanks! @AnisMansuri

Comment: I added the whole App Delegate code. Also, for SceneDelegate I have not messed with it. It's empty. Do I need to configure something there? And yeah I will attempt doing auto-layout again. Thanks! @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to detect anything. The *Info.plist* itself will arrange for the runtime to load a different storyboard depending on whether this is an iPad or not. There's a simple naming convention that governs this behavior: just make another key in the *Info.plist* ending in `~ipad`.

So, if you want to have two different main storyboards, use the *Info.plist* naming convention: configure two "Main storyboard file base name" keys, `UIMainStoryboardFile` and `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad` — or, with window scenes under iOS 13 and later, configure two "Application Scene Manifest" keys, `UIApplicationSceneManifest` and `UIApplicationSceneManifest~ipad`, that specify different `UISceneStoryboardFile` values.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I had seen that in another StackOverflow post and I had tried that as well, I just added an image and source code of my Info.plist. Let me know if that is correct.

Comment: I don't see why it would be correct. You didn't do what I said. You have, as I said, an application scene manifest. You need two of them.

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much! Sorry, for the misunderstanding I thought you meant UIMainStoryboardFile which I was doing. I added a second UIApplicationScene Manifest for iPad and it works now. Made my day. Have a good one brother!!